# Adding Button to table footer

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm looking for a way I can add a "Add New" button to my datatables footer area so that when clicked will send the user to the add new form. I've looked on the datatables website and not sure if I should be using this or not.

http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

Any other thoughts on this?

```
var oTable = $('#users').dataTable({
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sWidth": "60px", "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] },
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ -1 ] },
        { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ 0, -1 ] }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Does it need to be *in* the table footer?  Or could it just be below the table and styled to appear as related to the table?

Comment: `$('<div style="float:left;left:85px;padding:5px;"><button> Add New </button></div>').insertAfter('#example_info');` Run that in the console window on the page you linked. Something like that?

Comment: Here's how it looks http://jsfiddle.net/uf3v7/

Comment: So in other words its not showing anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need TableTools.

In datatables, you can set the `sDOM` property which specifies the DOM layout of the table.  You can read more about it [here](http://datatables.net/ref#sdom) but the main point of bringing it up is that it will allow you to specify a custom `div` to place in your footer.  You can then use jQuery to append your button to that div or something like that.  Furthermore, CSS should work fine for positioning that element within your footer.

[Here's more on the Datatables DOM settings](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

[And here's a good question in the Datatables forum that might help you out](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3914/adding-buttons-to-header-or-footer/p1)

Good luck!

**UPDATE:** I just went to your site and looked at your datatables setup.  Because you're using a template, the datatables code that they've provided has been bastardized to some extent - which in turn means that some of the 'defaults' that you may see in the datatables.net support site could not apply.  They definitely changed the `sDom` default.  Here's what they're using... :

```
'<"top"lf<"clear">>rt<"actions"<"actions-left"i><"actions-right"p>>'
```

It looks like "actions" is their footer `div`.  The easy way would be to dynamically add the button via `$(selector).append()`.  If you need help with that, I would visit the jQuery site.

Again - best of luck!

**UPDATE 2:** In response to your comment:

> What would be the selector then?

Your selector will be `'#actions'`.  But again - if you're unfamiliar with the `$` syntax above, you'll be doing yourself a favor by reading up on [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).  My apologies if you're already familiar with jQuery and were just looking for the selector ID to use (in which case, for future reference - anything in quotation marks within the datatables `sDom` parameter will be the ID for that `div` which you can use in your selector).

Comment: well it looks good however I don't have the sDom set. Its whatever it is by default. I just want to add something to it but don't know what the default is.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle and the js file with the datatables code that I have is      mydatatables.js in the footer and look for the table #users in the file. http://jsfiddle.net/wVrqS/

Comment: I found the two options that says its default BUT when I put both of those in as it says then it changes the layout of them so I don't understand my datatable.

Comment: Can you provide your javascript in the jsfiddle?  Right now you're just linking to external js files, so I can't tell any of your datatables settings.

Comment: The settings are inside of the mydatatables.js file.

Comment: What would be the selector then?